# Snowflake - How to view all stage files using show stage

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I used the below query in my worksheet. It ran successfully.

use database kaditdb;
use schema public;
show stages;

But when I click into Data preview button of Stages under Database section (left pane of classic console ) => Snowflake - Account usage ->Stages

[image]

Why are these files not known by show stages command?

Thanks.

Comment: Because that table shows the list of stages not the list of files within a stage

Comment: @NickW Both are stages only...

Comment: I'm not sure what your last comment means or its relevance to your question/my response? But it's no difference from you querying the TABLES table in the same schema - that will provide you with a list of tables but it won't show you the data within a specific table given in that list

Comment: @NIckW  Thanks to your response again. My question is , show stages for kaditdb.schema is returning nothing. Meaning there is not stage under this particular 'kaditdb.schema'. But , when i check with Snowflake->stages -> it shows stages belonging to all dbs in snowflake, where some of the stages say they belong to kaditdb. So why not, they come when 'show stages' .

Comment: Do you mean kaditdb.public rather than kaditdb.schema? Can you update your question to show the actual command you are running, and the context in which it is running?